# Package .NET framework DLL and use it in .NET standard project

Tags: visual-studio, dll, nuget, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

I have a vendor provided DLL which is based on .NET Framework. I do not have access to code and I only have the DLL. I have packaged this DLL into a nuget package and now I am trying to refer this into a .NET standard project. But I am getting warning as - **Package 'MyPackage 0.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.**.

If I refer the DLL directly into a .NET standard project it doesn't show this warning. But using it after creating a nuget package shows that.

I also tried creating a .NET standard lib project, added DLL reference and then created a nuget package but still it was showing same warning.

Is there another way of doing it? Vendor doesn't provide DLLs targeting other frameworks and I have to use it after packaging it into Nuget because of requirements.

Comment: How did you pack the dll into the net standard project?

Comment: @Perry Qian-MSFT I did not pack it into a net standard project. I first created a nuget package including the existing net framework DLL and then referred that nuget package into net standard project. That is when I am getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: Did you reference the net framework directly into the net standard nuget project?

Comment: [clean nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) and then install the nuget package to test whether the issue happens again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my side, I test the situation as you described. Create a net standard lib project called `test`, then use this node to include into the package.

**1)** create a net standard lib nuget project called `test` and only add this node under `test.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <None Include="xxx\xxx\xxx.dll"(the whole path of the net framework dll) Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\$(TargetFramework)"></None>
</ItemGroup>
```

**2)** right-click on the net standard test project-->click **Pack** button and you can get the new version of the nuget package.

[image]

**Before** you install the nuget package into another main project, you should [first clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`.

**And** I did not face the issue in my side with all the above steps.